# Stackexchange Redis exception: an unknown error occurred when writing the message

Tags: azure, asp.net-core-webapi, azure-redis-cache

.Net core 2.1 web-api uses below redis nuget package "StackExchange.Redis" Version="2.1.55" and connects to Azure Redis P1 tier, Redis version 4.0.14

On appsettings.config,

> "RedisConfiguration": {
> "ConnectionString": "mycache.redis.cache.windows.net:6380,password=$$$$$$$$$F543shkerXXXXXg=,ssl=True,abortConnect=False",
> "DatabaseNumber": 1   }

While performing load test,

Receiving below exception very frequently especially when maintaining 50requests/sec. Our application deployed on Azure service fabric cluster with 3 nodes. No processor/memory pressure observed on any of the server nodes.

> Message":"Redis exception while setting the value to cache: An unknown
> error occurred when writing the
> message","Level":"Error","ExceptionType":"StackExchange.Redis.RedisConnectionException
>
> "Message":"Redis exception while getting the value from cache: An
> unknown error occurred when writing the
> message","Level":"Error","ExceptionType":"StackExchange.Redis.RedisConnectionException"
> Complete stack trace for your reference:
>
> "StackTrace":" at
> StackExchange.Redis.ConnectionMultiplexer.ExecuteSyncImpl[T](Message
> message, ResultProcessor1 processor, ServerEndPoint server) in
> /*/src/StackExchange.Redis/ConnectionMultiplexer.cs:line 2800\r\n at
> StackExchange.Redis.RedisBase.ExecuteSync[T](Message message,
> ResultProcessor1 processor, ServerEndPoint server) in
> /*/src/StackExchange.Redis/RedisBase.cs:line 54\r\n at
> MyApplication.RedisCacheAdapter.<>c__DisplayClass21_1.b__0() in
> M:\work2\7ae5cc7915b5f803\MyApplication\RedisCacheAdapter.cs:line
> 199\r\n at Polly.Policy.<>c__DisplayClass144_0.b__0(Context
> ctx, CancellationToken ct)\r\n at
> Polly.RetrySyntax.<>c__DisplayClass5_1.b__1(Context ctx,
> CancellationToken ct)\r\n at
> Polly.Retry.RetryEngine.Implementation[TResult](Func3 action, Context
> context, CancellationToken cancellationToken, IEnumerable1
> shouldRetryExceptionPredicates, IEnumerable1
> shouldRetryResultPredicates, Func1 policyStateFactory)\r\n at
> Polly.RetrySyntax.<>c__DisplayClass5_0.b__0(Action2 action,
> Context context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n at
> Polly.Policy.ExecuteInternal(Action2 action, Context context,
> CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n at
> Polly.Policy.Execute(Action2 action, Context context,
> CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n at
> MyApplication.RedisCacheAdapter.Put(String key, Byte[] bytes, TimeSpan
> expirytime) in
> M:\work2\7ae5cc7915b5f803\MyApplication\RedisCacheAdapter.cs:line
> 196","Exception":"An unknown error occurred when writing the
> message","LoggerName":"MyApplication.RedisCacheAdapter","Message":"Redis
> exception while setting the value to cache: An unknown error occurred
> when writing the
> message","Level":"Error","ExceptionType":"StackExchange.Redis.RedisConnectionException"`

What would be reason for such error & how to fix this "StackExchange.Redis.RedisConnectionException"? Any change in redis connection string properties or redis version update would be useful?

Sometimes, below exception timeout exception as well when maintaining 50requests/sec on 3 nodes cluster

> "Message":"Redis Timeout exception occurred.

Answer (score 2):

You could put 'syncTimeout' parameter in ConnectionString like this

```
"RedisConfiguration": {"ConnectionString": "mycache.redis.cache.windows.net:6380,password=$$$$$$$$$F543shkerXXXXXg=,ssl=True,abortConnect=False,**syncTimeout=150000** "," DatabaseNumber ": 1}.
```

This parameter sets the "Time (ms) to allow synchronous operations", as can be seen at https://stackexchange.github.io/StackExchange.Redis/Configuration.html.

I had this problem when I stored items that took more than 5 seconds to be processed, since this is the default value. You can try increasing this value using the parameter inserted in the connection string. I hope I can help you with this, regards.

Answer (score 0):

It could be a problem with serializing and/or deserializering of cache items.

The first thing to do would be to check if it is allways the same cache items that fail. If that is the case what is special about these items.

Comment: That's useful though but the same cache items succeed sometimes also fails sometimes &, its quite sporadic. Is this something to do with Redis SDK version v2.1.55?

Comment: It could be the SDK verion 2.1.55 is not the latest. It is 7 months old and has 354 000 downloads. 2.1.58 is 6 months old and has 3 600 000 downloads. Based on that version 2.1.55 may have had bugs. Best to upgrade to latest